# Recursively parse a string of ones and zeroes into its decimal value

Tags: java, string, parsing, decimal, converters

My goal is to get a String of ones and zeroes from input, then use the bin2Dec method to parse that binary string into a decimal number. How can I convert this correctly?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a binary number string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The decimal value is " + bin2Dec(s));       
    }   
    public static int bin2Dec(String binaryString){       
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this? And what is a typical value of `s`?

Comment: Java. An input for s would be "110011"

Comment: Clearly, you need to actually write code that implements `bin2Dec`. Have you made any effort to do your assignment yourself? We usually don't answer "Here's what I need. Please write it for me. Be back later to pick it up." type questions. I'm certain that what your instructor is looking for is *your work* in completing the assignment and not ours.

Comment: The reason I am struggling is because it requires a return type int but I am supposed to be turning the string into decimal. I've messed around with a couple different things but ended up scrapping everything.

Comment: Most likely not Brady, that would ruin the entire point of the homework assignment.

Hint: bin2Dec method is going to need to take more than one parameter, you cannot pass enough information to solve this with your current set up.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm to do this is actually pretty simple.

If you look at a binary string, say, "10110" (22), what you'll notice is that equals 16 + 4 + 2. Look at this a bit harder, and you'll see it corresponds to **1** * 2^4 + **0** * 2^3 + **1** * 2^2 + **1** * 2^1 + **0** * 2^0. See the pattern? For each digit with value `v` and position `n`, it's "contribution" to the total sum is `v * 2^n`.

Now, this problem is actually easier to do iteratively (With a for-loop), but I assume this is a homework question and therefore you have to do it recursively.

You'll need to make another method, `public static int bin2dec(String bin, int position)` (this is called overloading the method, two methods can have the same name as long as their signatures are different). In this new method, you can follow the algorithm outlined above:

1. If `position` equals `bin.length()`, you've gone past the end of the string. Just return 0.
2. Otherwise, set `v` equal to the integer value of the character at `position` (You can either use the integer parse method, or just an `if`/ternary because there are only two options).
3. Multiply `v` by `2^position` (hint: `Math.pow`).
4. Return `v` plus `bin2dec(bin, position + 1)` (this is the actual recursive part).

Now, in the original `bin2dec`, you can just put `return bin2dec(bin, 0)`. That just allows you to call `bin2dec` without initializing the recursive counter, which is just general bookkeeping that callers don't want to deal with (not so important here, but very important in larger projects).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String showAsBinString(int n, String s){

    if(n > 1){
        s = showAsBinString(n/2, s);
    }
    s += n%2 == 0 ? "0" : "1";
    return s;

}
```

`System.out.println(showAsBinString(45, ""));`

101101